# How to delete DB table sql after certain time without upload

Tags: mysql, database

I've made a game system where I want the database table to automatically delete itself after maybe 30 minutes without any commands send to the table (Like SELECT, UPDATE etc.)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you pls explain why you want a table to be deleted? You can use temporary tables if you do not need a table permanently, but adding and removing tables on the fly is not really recommended.

Comment: Well, it a system where 2 players start a game, and creates a new table, when they both press "leave" it deletes itself, but often people just close the tab in their browser instead. But how would you make a temporary table?

Comment: Creating a new table for each game sounds like a poor -- or at least questionable -- design choice.

Comment: Yes, but I don't any access to sockets and it a simple 2 player in each game, game

Comment: Sorry, you should not create a table for this, not even a temporary one. You should store such data in a single table, where you have foreign keys to identify participants and  games.

Comment: ahm okayy, so like have a row with "server_name", "player_one", etc.?

Comment: Dropping a table sounds very bad, but if you need something done on a time-based interval, then you use MySQL's Event Scheduler (googling for that will set you on the proper path). Using the event scheduler, you can clean your db up and it can maintain itself basically (deleting obsolete data etc.).

Comment: Why don't you use sessions?

Comment: @stig-js How would you ever use that between 2 pc's?

Answer (score 1):

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl_name [(create_definition,...)] during the start of connection, and set the connection timeout (client side like mysqli or pdo mysql) to 30 minutes... provided that the implementation allows that two users share the same mysql connection.

though it is not recommended and i would rather use KVS like memcached for such purpose.

Comment: So.. How would I use KVS if that's recommended? And is the 30 minutes after last commands were send, or 30 minutes after creation?

Comment: before we move to next step, would you mind give some further details about what kind of data will be stored and used during the game?

Comment: Player name, id, choice (Rock, Scissors, Paper like), joined (whether the players actually in or not) and points. During the game points and choice will be the only rows that update a lot, the others might update do to leave and join, etc.

Comment: let's say we generate a memcache key "room1" with value "1" (which means open , 0 as closed), and expire value as 30 minutes.
p.s. player name, id is stored as a permanent table in mysql as you wish. After both players joined the game, keys "room1_p1_choice" and "room1_p2_choice" will be created , with possible values of 1, 2 or 3, and also keys "room1_p1_score" and "room1_p2_score", of course the expire is also set to 30 minutes. 
Every time a choice is made, all related keys' expire will be updated, and once the game ended, delete the key room1 and let the rest of the keys expire.

Comment: Arh okay, I think I know what you mean. So I should just make a table the way you described in the answer?

Comment: This answer is far from a good answer, and suggesting to use memcached is simply bad IMO. Also, the proposed solution of setting connection timeout won't work. Don't forget that preferred way of using PHP is via `php-fpm`. And FastCGI apps are long lived apps that are not working on a connection-per-request basis. As for what is and what isn't recommended.. MySQL's innodb is actually much quicker than memchahe is, plus `php-fpm` is able to cache the MySQL connection. It's not able to do so with memcache. Therefore, proposed solution (memcache) is actually worse.

Comment: well if you insist to use database only, then go ahead. But please be reminded that database is originally designed for storing permanent data, and storing data in a way of table instead of row is just violating the spirit(?) of rdbms

Comment: @KennethL. Well I've got no clue on how else to do this